# How can I find the average of a value, that is nested within another list when one element is a string, and the other int? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the average value of the second index in each list in the nested list, but have reached many error attempts so far. The data here is temporary, the user will input the data which makes up the master list. I need to output the average value of the integers here. For example the average would be 5.2 on this occasion. I am trying to get the sole number as output, and not a name associated with it.

```
master_list = [['Kevin', 10], ['Bob', 4], ['Alex', 1], ['Charles', 3], ['Robert', 4], ['David', 2], ['Kris', 5],
               ['Ben', 8], ['Paul', 6], ['Ben', 9]]
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need t simply ignore the names, access the numbers, and take the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension and pythons inbuilt `sum` and `len` functions:

```py
sum([a[1] for a in master_list])/len(master_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`statistics.mean()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#statistics.mean) on the second item of each sub list:

```
from statistics import mean

master_list = [['Kevin', 10], ['Bob', 4], ['Alex', 1], ['Charles', 3], ['Robert', 4], ['David', 2], ['Kris', 5], ['Ben', 8], ['Paul', 6], ['Ben', 9]]

avg = mean(item[1] for item in master_list)
print(avg)
```

Would output 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over your list of pairs, unpacking from every pair its elements, i.e `name` and `number`, and cumulatively built the total sum of numbers.

Then divide this total by number of pairs in your list, i.e. by `len(master_list)`:

```
total = 0
for pair in master_list:
    name, number = pair   # unpacking name, number from the [name, number] pair; see note
    total += num
    
average = total / len(master_list)
```

---

*Note:*

As names of persons are *out of our interest*, instead of the variable name `name` in the command

```
    name, number = pair
```

is a more Pythonic way using a special name `_` or `__` (one or two underline symbols):

```
    __, number = pair        # "__" means that we will not use it
```